# Facebook Sdk 4.0 how to check if logged in just after sdkinitialize

Tags: android, asynchronous, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

At the beginning of my first Activity I want to check if the user is already logged into facebook. The development site and another post on here say you have to check it with getcurrentaccesstoken(). Although this is valid, it seems that it is not accurate if you do this check just after you initialize facebooksdk. Like this:

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null || AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().isExpired()){
        // start loginactivity
    }
```

Since facebooksdk.initialize() gets the token out of shared preferences asynchronous the if statement is executed before sdkinitialize is done. So therefore AccessToken is always null.

I basically want to do this check right after the initialize, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You have to wait (Thread.Sleep or any) until `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize` done

Answer (score 0):

You could save and retrieve the access token yourself from shared preferences? When the user first logs in just save the access token then when you initialise facebook you can just get the token from shared preferences. Basically you will be doing what the facebook method is doing but you just won't need to wait.

Comment: Acesstoken is a class, not a string, bool, etc. So unfortunately I can't directly save the accestoken in shared preferences. I think facebook stores different values  in shared preferences to generate the specific AccessToken class for me.

Comment: Right but AccessToken.getCurrentAccesstoken returns a string so surely when the user logs in for the first time on success you can call the method and save the access token string it returns. then when they come to login again instead of calling AccessToken.getAccessToken() you can just call shared preferences yourself and get the access token out?

Comment: If I do this I can indeed check if he is already logged in but I also need the token to check if it is expired. I didn't put this in the code initially but I have added it now. Also, with the string value you can't really do anything as far as I know.